# Prepack.io with Ionic3 not generate file correctly

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, webpack, ionic2, ionic3

Iam try to make a demo with prepack using (prepack-webpack-plugin) and ionic i added

```
const PrepackWebpackPlugin = require('prepack-webpack-plugin').default;

const configuration = {};

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new PrepackWebpackPlugin(configuration)
  ]
};
```

to the node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
The app is build successfully but the app not generate main js needed to start app
what am i missing ?

Comment: The build chain of ionic (ionic-app-scripts) is pretty complex and has many different steps, webpack is just one of them, rewriting the bundle with prepack (which is highly experimental) may cause problems with the remaining build steps (such as uglifyjs).

Comment: so there is no chance i can run both

Comment: I would not say "no chance" as I did not try it myself but as I mentioned earlier the tool is experimental and the build process is compex enough without modifying it. You may get some error output when you run the build command in verbose mode (--verbose).